# Embedding Java Applet into html

Tags: java, html, japplet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Embedding Java Applet into .html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272666/embedding-java-applet-into-html-file)

I have Googled and researched still I don't understand where I am going wrong.

My program consists of three classes: `myFrame`, `myRightPanel` and `calculationEngine`. `myFrame` is the class which extends `JApplet`, I did this:

```
public class myFrame extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
      //bunch of things here
}
```

myRightPanel class and calculationEngine class are instantiated and used by myFrame. Whole code works fine in the applet viewer in eclipse. The trouble i am facing is in embedding it into an html. I did this and it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>    
      <body>
         <marquee>
            <h1> Ghun Chaatlo </h1></marquee>
            <applet code="myFrame.class" height="800" width= "1200"> 
            </applet>
        </body>
   </html>
```

All files: .html and .class files are in the same directory. But when I run the html, it doesn't show the applet. IDK why? Please help.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272666/embedding-java-applet-into-html-file

Comment: this post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999343/applet-code-tags-and-class-files

Comment: Are you loading the html page via the web server? or directly opening the file? When you load directly, the browser's security manager doesn't allow loading the applet.

Comment: directly! not with a server. i didnt know that, let me try putting it in the server.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you used html5. Here is the Best Way to Add A Java Applet to An HTML5 Document

```
<object type="application/x-java-applet" height="300" width="550">
  <param name="code" value="Sample" />
  <param name="archive" value="Sample.jar" />
  Applet failed to run.  No Java plug-in was found.
</object>
```